# Setting session variables

Tags: html, jsp

i have an html page that I connect to a servlet,
how can I set a session variable depending on the selection of a select tag? 
I had already used 1 form, so i can't use another one :-(.....
Can i use a button without using a form?

```
<li><a href="messaggiRicevuti?destinatario=0&mittente=1&sceltaTabellaMessaggiRicevuti">RICEVUTI</a>  
              <select name="sceltaTabellaMessaggiRicevuti"> 
                            <option value="msg_A" selected="selected">Alfa</option>
                            <option value="msg_B">Bravo</option>
                            <option value="msg_C">Charlie</option>
               </select>                 
</li>
```

Thanks

Comment: Think about using ajax for dropdown box onchange event.

Comment: Ok I solved submitting the form :-) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To access the servlet you have to submit the form (the servlet is executed on the server side). And the session variables have to be set on the server, so do this in your servlet, not in an html page.